# F# generating types in a type extension function within a type provider

Tags: f#, type-providers, type-extension

I have the following problem:

Within my type provider, I need to extend a generic type, that I have previously defined, with a method that will return an instance of this generic type. 
What I mean is, let's say we have :

```
type receiveType<'a> = class
   val Next:int
   val Type:string
   new (state,stateType) =
      {Next = state;Type = stateType;}                    
   end
```

later within my typeprovider I want to extend the type with the following function:

```
[<TypeProvider>] 
type ProviderTest() as this= (
   inherit TypeProviderForNamespaces() 
   let ns = "typeProviderTest.Provided"    
   let asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

   let makeAType (s:string) =
      let typage =
         ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, s, Some typeof<obj>) 
      typage

   type receiveType<'a> with
      member this.receive(hey:'a,next:string)= 
         // generate a type from a string for instance
         // "hello" -> type helloType
         generateTypeFromString(next) 
        // let typage = ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, next, Some typeof<obj>)
        new receiveType<nextType>(5,"hello")
```

The goal here for me is to generate an instance of the type `receiveType<TypeHello>` , iterate through a structure (Finite State Machine) to get the next possible message I can receive ( for instance `"goodMorning"`), create the type associated ( `TypeGoodMorning` ) and then generate an instance of `receiveType<TypeGoodMorning>`.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to create a function that would return values of different types on every call?

Comment: In a way yes. But I want to generate the type of the value, to be returned on every call, from a string. Which means for a specific call of the function, with the string `"Hello"` for instance as an argument, I want to generate the type `HelloType` and return a value of type `receiveType<HelloType>`

Comment: In a statically typed language, you can't make a function that has different return type depending on the argument value. This would defeat the whole idea of static typing: being able to verify program correctness before execution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would however want to ask you something. Let's say that I want to use this code to implement a protocol of communication. For instance I am a user that have the following code : `channel.send(Hello()).receive(something)' this `something` that I receive, I want it to be of type `Response` so that I can be sure that the one I speak with sends me a message of type `Response` and then follows the protocol. Thus,`receive()` needs an argument of type `Response`. Therefore, the only way would be to have `Response` type statically defined? Thank you again for your time.