# F# generic type instanciation from object and not type

Tags: generics, f#

Let's say we have the following type which does nothing for the moment

```
type Foo<'a,'b> = 
   new () = {}
```

We want to instanciate it like this

```
type First = class end

let first = new Foo<First,First>()
```

And what I want to do right now is to instanciate the next object to be something like

```
let second = new Foo<first.GetType(),First>()
```

However I can't do `first.GetType()` to provide it with a type. So I thought of binding the type to a value of type `System.Type` and use it like the following

```
let typing = first.GetType()
let second = new Foo<typing,First>()
```

But it says that the type `typing` is not defined, instead of taking the type of `first`.
How can I be able to do something like `let second = new Foo<first.getType(),First>()` ?

Edit:
More details here about what I am trying to aim for:
let's say we have a protocol of communication on a channel `channel`. The protocol of communication is defined using a Map like the following :

```
[(currentState:Int , nextState:Int , type:string , label:string) -> realType:Type ]
```

for instance

```
[(currentState:1 , nextState:2 , type:"send" , label:"hello()") -> realType:Hello ;
  (currentState:2 , nextState:3 , type:"receive" , label:"bye()") -> realType:Bye]
```

What I want from that is to generate the following functions

```
send(a:Hello)
receive(a:Bye)
```

but such that, as you can see in the Map, `receive(a:Bye)` cannot be done before `send(a:Hello)` or there will be an error at compile-time. It should follow the correct sequence. That's the reason why to do that I want to instanciate a type of type receiveType as the return value of the `send(a:Hello)` function allowing me to use the `receive(a:Bye)` in the following way :

```
channel.send(Hello()).receive(Bye())
```

The last thing is that the Map can have more states than these 2, the length depends on the protocol I use. And the whole idea will be implemented within a type provider so that I can provide types and methods that I just described using intelliSense.

Related question: [F# generating types in a type extension function within a type provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139024/f-generating-types-in-a-type-extension-function-within-a-type-provider)

Comment: You can't do that. How would you be able to use such a type without knowing what the type parameters are statically?

Comment: Well I thought that I would use that inside a type provider. And i also thought that maybe it is used in a type provider and the type provider is compiled when you use it in a script. Which would mean that the type is already defined in a way. But now that I think about it, I will give a parameter to the type provider and then from the parameter create those types, so it is not possible. But then this kind of code can only be done in a dynamically type language is that correct like python? And what do you mean by type parameters here?

Comment: By type parameters I mean the types you provide for `'a` and `'b'` when defining an instance of `Foo`. You have to statically declare a type for both of these which you did with `First` i.e. `new Foo<First, First>`. But `first.GetType()` returns an object which represents a type at runtime. Python cannot represent this relationship since Python doesn't have types at all, but it's difficult to know what you're trying to do with this example. Are you trying to write a type provider or do you just need a generic data type?

Comment: You cannot do this directly, because types need to be known at compile time, so that the program's correctness may be verified. The whole point of static typing, you know. But you might get away with some creative metaprogramming: http://fsoikin.blogspot.ru/2014/05/dynamic-generics-in-net.html

Comment: @Lee Thank you for your reply, Yes I am trying to write a type provider where I will provide Map of string to Types  for instance "hello" to `Hello`. And the goal will be to go through this Map and generate methods that have arguments of type the type I got from the Mapping. The goal will be to assure that the sequence of interaction I want to do Is correct. For instance let's say we have 2 Types `Hello` and `Bye` in the Map. The goal will be to generate the following methods: `receive(a:Hello)` and `receive(a:Bye)` and to use them like this : `channel.receive(new Hello()).receive(new Bye())`

Comment: and if you write this for instance: `channel.receive(new Bye).receive(new Hello())` it will raise an error at compile-time saying that channel has only the method `receive(a:Hello)` and not `receive(a:Bye)`. That's pretty much the goal. This will allow me at compile-time to assure that I correctly follow a protocol of communication for instance. @FyodorSoikin   Thank you for you message. I understand that this is the whole goal of static typing but it's quite frustrating in a way. Thank you also for the link I will look into it .

Comment: This is not how you construct an API for communication protocol. Here is a suggestion: first try to write (a portion of) the protocol manually, without type providers, then see if some of those types lend themselves to autogeneration. Don't try to be a hammer.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin thank you for the advices. I'll do that, I'll see how those types work with the protocol.

Comment: Well, you can always write a function that pattern matches on the dynamically inferred type and returns the instance with appropriate static type parameters statically set. The limitation then is that then your match must have a case for every type of the type parameter you intend to use. By using flexible types as type parameters you can achieve more flexibility. But as was mentioned before, first get your architecture right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating an instance of a generic type whose type arguments differ from those of an existing object, can be done at run time using the methods `GetGenericTypeDefinition` and `MakeGenericType`.

So, given your example:

```
type Foo<'a,'b> = 
    new () = {}

type First = class end

let first = new Foo<First,First>()
```

The steps are:

1. Get the generic type without any type arguments:

   ```
   let genericFooType = first.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()
   ```
2. Make a new generic type with the appropriate type arguments:

   ```
   let secondType = genericFooType.MakeGenericType(first.GetType(), typeof<First>)
   ```
3. Create the instance of the new type via an appropriate constructor. In this case there's a single constructor with no parameters:

   ```
   let second = secondType.GetConstructor([||]).Invoke([||])

   second.GetType() = typeof<Foo<Foo<First,First>, First>> // True
   ```

If you need to know any of the type arguments of the type of the original object, they can be retrieved as follows:

```
let originalTypeArguments = first.GetType().GenericTypeArguments

// Prints [|"First"; "First"|]
printfn "%A" (originalTypeArguments |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Name))
```